# Sveltekit and tailwind multiple condition in style

Tags: css, tailwind-css, sveltekit

I have this style conditions in an element:

```
<input class="{isCompact ? (img !== null ? 'pr-5':'pr-2') : (img !== null ?  'pr-7':'pr-4')  } "
```

if `isCompact` is true then it will use the first conditional statements, the ones with smaller padding, and if false, it will use the second one.

How do I add more internal conditions alongside the `img !== null`

I tried doing the following but it messed up the styles:

```
<input class="{isCompact ? 
((img !== null ? 'pr-5':'pr-2') + (isDisabled ? 'bg-gray-100':'' ) 
:
((img !== null ? 'pr-7':'pr-4') + (isDisabled ? 'bg-gray-200':'' ) 
} "
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add spaces between the classes, so the latter ones should just start with one.

The logic could also be extracted into a function in the `<script>` and the classes be collected in an array, then you can just return `classes.join(' ')`.

Answer (score 0):

Tbh I would suggest you to use something like https://github.com/lukeed/clsx instead, or write your own utility, it will make your code much more readable this way:

```
<input
  class={clsx(
    isCompact
      ? {
          'pr-5': img,
          'pr-2': !img,
          'bg-gray-100': isDisabled,
        }
      : {
          'pr-7': img,
          'pr-4': !img,
          'bg-gray-200': isDisabled,
        },
  )}
/>
```

You can write it in a different way, just check their examples too.